# jqPlot repeating values on Y axis

Tags: jqplot

I have a graph which values on Y axis can quite vary. The only information I have is:

- all values are integers
- the value are >=0

Now if I have just few values with very low volatility like (lets take the extreme) `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` I got on my Y axis repetitive values. It looks like:

```
 |
1+
 |
1+
 |
1+
 |
0+
 |
0+
 |
0+-----------------------------------------
```

What I would like to achieve is to make jqPlot skip the repetitive values, possibly display only 2 ticks - 0,1 on the Y axis (the very bottom and very top one).

Any ideas? Adding my code for reference:

```
yaxis:{
    label:'Count',
    padMin: 0,
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions:{
       formatString:'%d'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bug with the plugin, I can reproduce it on their demo code and I have the same problem myself.

for now set the chart to a smaller dimension as that's the current flaw with the plugin.

hope this helped.

Comment: Ok, will raise have look if I can raise a bug somehow ... Cheers

Comment: @Jan Zyka I am facing the same issue. Did you file a bug report? If yes, can you please link it here?

Answer (score 2):

This is no bug at all. jqplot uses some kind of zoom in their graphics, so when you say `formatString:'%d'` you're forcing to show the int value in the y-axis. Deleting this line it will fall back to values like `1.3, 1.8, ...` or so. I guess you want to show tickInterval of int values (I found this post seeking this same problem without response).

Guess this can't be done yet

Comment: sorta is, I mean it should try to better handle this short coming than repeating the same number.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show only integer digits, you you may use custom string formatter:

```
 tickOptions:{
   formatString:'%d',
   formatter: yourCustomFormater
}
```

Where 'yourCustomFormatter' is enhanced default '$.jqplot.DefaultTickFormatter' :

```
var yourCustomFormatter = function (format, val) {
    if (typeof val == 'number') {
        if (!format) {
            format = $.jqplot.config.defaultTickFormatString;
        } 

        if (val % 1 === 0) {
            return $.jqplot.sprintf(format, val);
        } else {
            //ignore items with not integer values
            return '';
        }
    }
    else {
        return String(val);
    }
};
```

But be aware this formatter by default affects labels on your bar unless you use any other highlighter plugins.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

`axes:{
      xaxis:{
            numberTicks: 2
      }
}`

Comment: Please add more details to your answer to make it more useful to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

for me the below fixed the issue:
1- parameter tickOptions was tickOptions: {formatString: "%d"} I changed it to be tickOptions: {formatString: "%.2f"} because in case two elements rounded to the same integer value, its tick shows twice,

2- I've added extra parameter numberTicks: 4 to let axis has only 4 plots

with these two changes the current issue has been fixed but it may appears again according to the passed data to the graph